# send dbmail on @@error from sql server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sp-send-dbmail, dbmail

I am trying to send database mail when error occurs inside the transaction.My setup for dbo.sp_send_dbmail is correct , when I execute the proc I do get an email within 1 min.

However when I try to use dbo.sp_send_dbmail inside another proc within transactions than I do not get the email. Sql server does show in the result window that "Mail queued" but I never receive it.

> BEGIN TRANSACTION
>
> DECLARE @err int 
>   DECLARE @test nvarchar(max)
>
> RAISERROR('This is a test', 16, 1)
>   SELECT @err = @@ERROR
>
> IF  @err <> 0
>   BEGIN
>
> SET @test = error_message()
>
> EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
>         @recipients= 'mail@mail.net',
>         @body = 'test inside', 
>         @subject = 'Error with proc',
>         @body_format = 'HTML',
>         @append_query_error = 1,
>         @profile_name ='Database Mail Profile';
>
> ROLLBACK TRANSACTION 
>    RETURN
>   END
>
> COMMIT TRANSACTION

And I get result as

> Msg 50000, Level 16, State 1, Line 7 
>   This is a test 
>   Mail queued.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You rolled it back so it never went out, put the email code outside the transaction

From books on line

> When executing sp_send_dbmail from
>   within an existing transaction,
>   Database Mail relies on the user to
>   either commit or roll back any
>   changes. It does not start an inner
>   transaction.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190307.aspx

Comment: humm that is what i thought initially...however I thought it would be like a print statement...u know...shoot and forget kind of a thing because it is executing the proc....I even tried by putting the mail code outside the begin end but it still does not work....

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a savepoint, attempt your operation, in case of error rollback to the savepoint, send the mail message then commit. Similar to the pattern described in [Exception handling and nested transactions](http://rusanu.com/2009/06/11/exception-handling-and-nested-transactions/).